# How do I open folders containing a blank in a quicklist?

Tags: unity, nautilus, quicklists

I am having problems when I want to use a folder name containing a blank (*Hentede filer* in my case). It is in the line: `Exec= Hentede filer` of the .desktop file but that doesn't work.

```
[Downloads Shortcut Group]
Name=Hentede filer
Exec=nautilus Hentede filer
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Answer (score 8):

Change it to `nautilus "Hentede filer"`

For future reference: you can test these by issueing the command in a terminal like so:

[image: im1].

It will open it if it the command is correct or give an error message if it is not. Since I do not have a "Hentede filer" I get this message:

[image: im2]

But as you can see it errors out on not finding it but it does show it tries to open it  the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to:

```
[Downloads Shortcut Group]
Name=Hentede filer
Exec=nautilus Hentede\ filer
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

In fact, in linux blanks are identified by the "`\`" key code (backslash+blank).

Comment: Actually, the "\" (backslash) is used to prefix characters that cannot be entered as-is. So, when you enter "Hentede\ filer" the space will be made part of the parameter, not a parameter separator.